# ARM GCC with Cygwin on Windows 8.1 : fatal error: no input file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cygwin

I am newbie for Linux and build systems and I am trying to move code base from Linux to Windows. I am getting some issues for build.

I have installed

- cygwin
- arm-none-eabi-gcc from https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

and when I build my application, I am getting following error :

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error:
/cygdrive/d/developments/RIOT/examples/ipc_pingpong/main.c: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

It looks like a path problem between cygwin (cygdriver) and windows. I have also set `CYGPATH` as **c:\cygwin64\bin\cygpath.exe** but result is same.

Why gcc compiler cannot see my files? Any idea.

Regards.

Murat.

Comment: Have you checked if the path exists within cygwin by doing e.g. `$ ls /cygdrive/d/developments/RIOT/examples/ipc_pingpong/main.c`? How did you set the `CYGPATH` environment variable? `$ set CYGPATH=C:/cygwin/bin/cygpath.exe` from the cygwin shell (which is bash, iirc) won't work. Try the method in https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_advancd_environmnt_addchange_variable.mspx?mfr=true.

Comment: I have checked file with $ls and also see content with $cat and it can find file. 
I have already set CYGPATH like as your microsft link.

Comment: Not sure what's going on then. You could `$ echo $CYGPATH` too, just as a sanity check.

Comment: $ echo $CYGPATH

-> C:\cygwin64\bin\cygpath.exe

Comment: the error message is indicating that the main.c file is located on the windows 'd:\' drive in directory:' /developments/RIOT/examples/ipc_pingpong/'  and the error message is saying that the file (and possibly the directory path) is not correct.  Suggest fixing those details.

Comment: I am checking files but I could not see any issue. 

I have also added following lines to .bashrc under cygwin/home/<user>
 - export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/gnu
 - export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/gnu/bin
 - export CYGPATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/cygpath.exe

but result is same. I am using 64 Bit Windows 8. Can it be about my OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried MinGW instead of Cygwin and problem is solved.

Following link is very helpfull for MinGW setup : 
http://www.jann.cc/2013/10/10/embedded_development_with_open_source_tools_on_windows.html

Thanks. 
Murat

Answer (score 3):

At this point the arm-none-eabi toolchain from https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded doesn't support being invoked from Cygwin cmake/make as it doesn't understand Cygwin style absolute path specifications passed.  Anecdotally it will work with a makefile that contains solely relative paths, however cmake generates makefiles with absolute paths.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1282943

Answer (score 1):

Check output of command

```
which gcc
```

If you can find the path of gcc file you are fine. If you could not please modify the env varibale PATH by including the path of gcc as follows.
If full path of gcc file  is  $/gcc, then you have to correct $PATH as follows

```
$PATH:$GCC_PATH
```

$PATH may be defined within .profile file of your home directory.

Comment: result of which gcc is 
/usr/bin/gcc

And path is already defined as GCC_PATH (C:/gnu)

Comment: Check value of env variable PATH as follows:
echo $PATH and please share

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Acer/abFiles:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:

Comment: continue'd   : 

/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/gnu:/cygdrive/c/gnu/bin:/:/cygdrive/c/gnu/4.9-2014q4/bin:/cygdrive/c/gnu/bin

Comment: Gcc compiler is located under c:\gnu

Comment: where is gcc located, is answered by output of command which gcc and that path /usr/bin is part of your variable PATH. So it should not be an issue. Can you please share the program and command using to compile it

Comment: I am trying to build only RIOT on Windows. You can clone it from https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT

please go to RIOT/examples/ipc_pingpong directory and build with following command : make BOARD=mbed_lpc1768

Comment: the gcc compiler should be in /usr/bin, not c:/gnu

Comment: If GCC_PATH is a variable in makefile  please correct its value as /usr/bin/ else please check your makefile and find the GCC path

Comment: I cannot change makefile. 
It looks like there is no problem with gcc. I think gcc compiler cannot see source files (e.g. main.c).

Comment: Is there anybody can build RIOT in own local :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today - and found a way to convince the non-cygwin applicaction to treat `c:/cygdrive/c/` as link to my `/cygdrive/c` folder using a windows symlink:

(Run `cmd` as administrator)

```
mkdir c:\cygdrive
cd c:\cygdrive
mklink /d c c:\
```

see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html The CYGWIN environment variable

```
export CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native
cd c:/cygdrive/c
ln -s c:/VSARM vsarm
```

Comment: This workaround works for me. Improved answer by adding code showing how to create the windows symlink.